# Limit open connections at any one time, maintain rate of X users per second?

Tags: gatling

I'm writing a Gatling load test which simply bombards a given endpoint over HTTP for a given period of time. I have it gradually ramp up connections per second, and then hold it there for the duration of the test. My setup looks like this:

```
setUp(
    scn.inject(
        rampUsersPerSec(10 to 70 during(1 minute),
        constantUsersPerSec(70) during(9 minutes)
    ).protocols(httpConf).throttle(jumpToRps(70) holdFor(10 minutes))
)
```

This works, but the problem is that our requests take a long time, sometimes much longer than a second.

What ends up happening is that the server slows down and requests start taking longer and longer, and instead of maintaining 70 connections to the server at a time, this quickly grows linearly and I'll have something like 1000 open connections at any given time.

Is there a way to "limit the pool" of Gatling users to maintain X open connections at a given time? I've so far been unsuccessful in trying to throttle it.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is a closed injection model.

In order to do that with Gatling, you have to wrap your scenario content with a loop, and possible flush the HTTP caches and cookie jars. Search the doc.

Note that this model is nowhere realistic, except if your system indeed limit the number of users that it lets enter, with an upfront queue. Typical use case is a call center.

Comment: I'll try that out. I've been having a difficult time with the docs.